# Is it possible to return by a function from nested loop (HELP)

Tags: python, arrays, nested-loops

[I am trying to return from function 'letter' the following output as shown on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHXyl.png)

Comment: What's your attempt?

Comment: to get the full array if i typed one letter in the defined function

Comment: so the function has to loop the list and look for the letter..

Comment: So confirm the answer plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
v = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]


def letter(n):
  res = []
  for item in v:
    if n in item:
      res.append(item)
  return res


print(letter('a'))  # [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'f', 'g']]
```

Comment: So confirm the answer plz